# Where is the documentation for the "path" taskelement in Ant?

Tags: ant, documentation

I must be missing something obvious here... I found the online documentation for the [`<property>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html)  task, but I can't find it for the `<path>` task, e.g.:

```
<path id="client.classpath">
   <fileset dir="${libDir}">
       <include name="*.jar"/>
   </fileset>
</path>
```

Where is `<path>` documented?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Right here: [Path-like Structures](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#path) in Ant manual.

Comment: oh. {sheepish look} I guess I was expecting a separate page that had "<path>" at the top.

Comment: The Ant docs are pretty bad, to be fair. They need some serious attention.

Comment: Ant needs to be taken out and shot.  Thanks for the <path> tag reference, though!